# Checking elements in multiple columns of Dataframe in Julia

Tags: dataframe, loops, julia

I have a question regarding the use of conditions in any loop while manipulating on DataFrame.

For example,
I have a DataFrame

```
df:

a b c

1 2 5
3 4 3
2 1 7
6 3 6
5 1 9
```

I am trying to write a loop with a condition which checks on two cols (`a and b`) at a time and if the value `i` is available in either or both column then it should take the values from column `c` and store it in an array.

Using which I can later perform the statistical operations like finding mean of the array.

I have written a simplified code snippet for this task:

```
for i in 1:5
  result1 = Float64[]
  result2 = Float64[]
  if (df[:, :a] = i) 
      push!(result1, df[:, :c])
  elseif (df[:, :b] = i)
      push!(result2, df[:, :c])
  end

  unique!(result1)
  unique!(result2)

  result = vcat(result1, result2)

  global mean_val = mean(result)
end
```

Here, the `i` value will range from 1 to 5 and for each value both the columns `a and b` will be checked for its existence, if the value exist then value in column `c` should be pushed to the respected result array.

I have tried using some other suggestions from community like:

Code Example 1:

```
for i in 1:5
  mean_val = mean(df[:, :c] for i in ("a", "b")
end
```

Code Example 2:

```
for i in 1:5
  df.row = axes(df, 1)
  mean_val = mean((filter(x->x[:a] == i || x[:b] == i ,df))[:c])
end
```

However these do not work and return a desired output.

Please advice on my mistake in the code.
Also, please do suggest if there is any document which explains about implementing multiple conditions in a statement, and accessing dataframe elements for any other operations in julia.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first way to do what (I think) you want to achieve would be to use the [indexing syntax](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/getting_started/#Indexing-syntax) to take a subset of your dataframe:

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> df = DataFrame(a = rand(1:5, 10), b = rand(1:5, 10), c = rand(1:100, 10))
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      2     25
   2 │     5      4     72
   3 │     4      3     37
   4 │     4      3     46
   5 │     3      2     31
   6 │     3      5     43
   7 │     5      1     35
   8 │     5      2     54
   9 │     1      1     64
  10 │     1      4     57
```

```
julia> idx = (df.a .== 3) .| (df.b .== 3)
10-element BitArray{1}:
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0

julia> filtered_c = df[idx, :c]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 37
 46
 31
 43
```

You can then compute any statistics you want on the resulting filtered values:

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> mean(filtered_c)
39.25
```

---

Another way of doing the same thing would rely on the use of [`filter`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Base.filter) to filter the rows you want to keep:

```
julia> filtered_df = filter(row -> (row.a==3 || row.b==3), df)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     4      3     37
   2 │     4      3     46
   3 │     3      2     31
   4 │     3      5     43

# This way of writing things is equivalent to the previous one, but
# might be more readable in cases where the condition you're checking
# is more complex
julia> filtered_df = filter(df) do row
           row.a == 3 || row.b == 3
       end
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     4      3     37
   2 │     4      3     46
   3 │     3      2     31
   4 │     3      5     43

julia> mean(filtered_df.c)
39.25
```

Answer (score 3):

As a small efficiency note to an excellent answer by François Févotte, it is faster to do:

```
julia> filter([:a, :b] => (a,b) -> a == 3 || b == 3, df, view=true)
4×3 SubDataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     3      5      1
   2 │     3      5      9
   3 │     4      3     74
   4 │     4      3     63
```

if you have a very large data frame. There are two differences here:

1. I use a `[:a, :b] => (a,b) -> a == 3 || b == 3` synax, which is type stable (so it will iterate rows faster);
2. I use `view=true` to produce a view of a source data frame, which allocates much less (it might matter for very large data frames);

Here is a small example of different row subsetting options you have on a larger data frame:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=rand(1:3, 10^8), b=rand(1:3, 10^8), c=rand(10^8));

julia> function test()
           @time filter(row -> (row.a==3 || row.b==3), df)
           @time df[(df.a .== 3) .| (df.b .== 3), :]
           @time @view df[(df.a .== 3) .| (df.b .== 3), :]
           @time filter([:a, :b] => (a,b) -> a == 3 || b == 3, df)
           @time filter([:a, :b] => (a,b) -> a == 3 || b == 3, df, view=true)
           return nothing
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test()
 19.912672 seconds (333.67 M allocations: 6.652 GiB, 5.71% gc time, 0.41% compilation time)
  1.152460 seconds (29 allocations: 1.667 GiB, 14.88% gc time)
  0.515334 seconds (15 allocations: 435.807 MiB, 40.49% gc time)
  1.066756 seconds (412.82 k allocations: 1.689 GiB, 5.56% gc time, 12.54% compilation time)
  0.646710 seconds (382.98 k allocations: 455.835 MiB, 31.27% gc time, 23.02% compilation time)

julia> test()
 18.194791 seconds (333.34 M allocations: 6.635 GiB, 4.87% gc time)
  1.018816 seconds (29 allocations: 1.667 GiB, 15.34% gc time)
  0.469027 seconds (15 allocations: 435.807 MiB, 41.19% gc time)
  0.912572 seconds (30 allocations: 1.667 GiB, 5.32% gc time)
  0.480374 seconds (16 allocations: 435.807 MiB, 41.15% gc time)
```

Comment: what about to find a value in the whole dataset without iterating, let's say find the value "ND" ?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. In order to continue with nature of the question, let's say you want to find a particular value in each column of your data set. would you use `stack`  or `describe` with a formula? In the comment I asked for the value "ND" , the use case I am working on I have to check every column with that value. what would you recommend it's the best way. Thanks Bogumil!

Comment: But the question is what you mean by "find". Do you want to count them, or select rows that in at least one column contain this value? Maybe it would be easiest if you opened a new question and show a sample input and a desired output. Thank you!